# Check page height with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there way to check page height?

Like If I have `container div` and my contents goes of `100% height`.
I need to check full height of that container div.

Like if it is `100% + more 400px`  I want to add something next to that div.

Comment: You can use $( 'div').height()

Comment: Or outerHeight? if i have margins and padding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('.container div').outerHeight();
```

codepen-http://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/XKZgyq

Add if condition for that value
var x =   $('.container div').outerHeight();

Update x ,onresize check x value greater than x+400px

Answer (score 0):

Page height is a native javascript property. 
Just do a

```
    window.innerHeight
```

to get the current window height which works well since it only includes from the bottom tool/search bar to the end of browser